# How to return http 304 NOT_MODIFIED if Spring Rest gets a cache hit and If-Modified-Since header

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, caching, http-headers

In an Spring Restful Server, is it possible to return a HTTP response with empty body and return code `304 NOT MODIFIED` if Spring hits the cache of an `@Cacheable GET` endpoint **and** `If-Modified-Since` header of the request is as old as the change date of the requested resource on the server?

Of course, regarding the latter case with the appropriate cache http headers, I could implement that logic in the endpoint, but this seems both not to be very convenient and not compatible to the automatic caching annotations of Spring.